# Get more verbose template trace in gcc or clang diagnostics

Tags: gcc, g++, clang++

When an error happens while expanding templates, the compiler prints the chain of templates being instantiated. In older gcc the trace looked like (edit: actually it seems to do this for function templates, but not for class templates)

```
... while expanding whatever<X, Y, Z> with [X=int, Y=double, Z=other]
```

but in g++ 4.8 and clang++ 3.3 it looks like

```
required from whatever<int, double, other>
```

While this is shorter, it is also *completely unreadable* when the template has 10 arguments and most of them are templates whose arguments in turn are more templates and so on several layers deep. Then it just melts into completely unintelligible mess of angle brackets (that are not treated as parenthesis in editor, so it's difficult to even copy&paste&format it).

Is there any way to force the more verbose format from either of the two compilers?

If there was a way to additionally get it expanded to separate lines like

```
... while expanding whatever<X, Y, Z> with
    X=int
    Y=double
    Z=other
```

(somewhat like MSC++ does), it would be nice bonus.

Comment: Please post a code that produces such an error.

Comment: IMO, TMP tracing and error messages are one of the worst aspects of current compilers. Maybe it should be considered a deficiency of the language itself.